# Insert data into ttk.treeview widget to specific column

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I'd like to insert data into a specific column of my ttk treeview widget. The users only input is a scanner, so I have to parse each code to determine which column it goes into. Right now, the `parseData()` function runs on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, so I would like to take care of the insert there.

I have tried using the `treeview.set(item, column, new_value)`, but it falls apart when inserting into a blank row.

```
class MainGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.data_view = ttk.Treeview(master)
        self.data_view['columns'] = ["Date", "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Source", "Destination", "Cart #",]
        self.data_view['show'] = 'headings'
        self.data_view.heading("Date", text="Date")
        self.data_view.heading("Item 1", text="Item 1")
        self.data_view.heading("Item 2", text="Item 2")
        self.data_view.heading("Item 3", text="Item 3")
        self.data_view.heading("Item 4", text="Item 4")
        self.data_view.heading("Source", text="Source")
        self.data_view.heading("Destination", text="Destination")
        self.data_view.heading("Cart #", text="Cart #")
        self.data_view.pack()

        self.scan_entry = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.scan_entry.pack()
        self.scan_entry.bind('<Return>', self.parseEntry)
        self.scan_entry.focus()

        self.close_button = tk.Button(master, text="Close", command=self.adminLogout, width=15, height=5)
        self.close_button.pack(anchor='se')

    def parseEntry(self,event):
        #INSERT self.scan_entry.get() into #ITEM 1 column, not date volumn
        #If contains certain characters, maybe insert into Source or Destination
        self.scan_entry.delete(0,'end')
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to insert into the blank tree to any column, or in some cases grab what is selected, then change the value based on input.

Comment: Is `self.data_view.insert('', 'end', values=('', self.scan_entry.get()))` what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to insert empty in the columns you do not want to fill.

And you can use `in` to check for the character you seek in `self.scan_entry.get()`:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
class MainGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.data_view = ttk.Treeview(master)
        self.data_view['columns'] = ["Date", "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Source", "Destination", "Cart #",]
        self.data_view['show'] = 'headings'
        self.data_view.heading("Date", text="Date")
        self.data_view.heading("Item 1", text="Item 1")
        self.data_view.heading("Item 2", text="Item 2")
        self.data_view.heading("Item 3", text="Item 3")
        self.data_view.heading("Item 4", text="Item 4")
        self.data_view.heading("Source", text="Source")
        self.data_view.heading("Destination", text="Destination")
        self.data_view.heading("Cart #", text="Cart #")
        self.data_view.pack()
        self.scan_entry = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.scan_entry.pack()
        self.scan_entry.bind('<Return>', self.parseEntry)
        self.scan_entry.focus()

        self.close_button = ttk.Button(master, text="Close", command=lambda:print('want to close app'))
        self.close_button.pack(anchor='se')

    def parseEntry(self,event):
        #self.scan_entry.delete(0,'end')
        self.data_view.insert('',END,values=('',self.scan_entry.get(),'','','','','',''))
        #If contains certain characters, maybe insert into Source or Destination       
        if 'a' in self.scan_entry.get():
            self.data_view.insert('',END,values=('','','','','',self.scan_entry.get(),self.scan_entry.get(),''))


if __name__=='__main__':
    master=Tk()
    maingui=MainGUI(master)
    master.mainloop()
```

Comment: In your code each value create a new row at the end is it possible to insert the new value row at the top of the table inside a specific column even if i have already inserted few rows to the table.

Comment: Yes. Use the iid argument to give each row a unique ID when you are initially creating it, then you can later reference that iid and the respective column to insert data.